# Creating colored text icon to use in php script (see image)

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to be able to create icons/colored CSS text blocks such as these:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2uzEUuk.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rf89BRN.png]

I have no idea where to start looking for these as I have no idea wather this is HTML, PHP, or just CSS or a combination of them.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have looked at the source code, but all I see is that they are class files to something, can't trace it down.

Comment: How about looking at the source of the pages that has the types of icons that you like?

Comment: Start with: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these look like **[Bootstrap Badges or Labels](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges)** with some kind of icon font. **[Lots of Icon Fonts](http://weloveiconfonts.com/)**

They are also quite simple to use...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tVbvJ/1/)**

```
<span class="label">Default Label <i class="icon-globe icon-white"></i></span>
<span class="label label-success">Success Label <i class="icon-tag icon-white"></i></span>
<span class="label label-important">Important Label <i class="icon-hand-right icon-white"></i></span>
<span class="label label-warning">Warning Label <i class="icon-hand-left icon-white"></i></span>
```

Results in:

[image: Bootstrap + Glyphicons]

It also wouldn't be that difficult to craft your own with a little bit of CSS and some icon-fonts.
HTML:

```
<span class="label"><span class="fontelico-emo-beer"></span> Beer Me!</span>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontelico);

/* fontelico */
[class*="fontelico-"]:before {
  font-family: 'fontelico', sans-serif;
}
.label{
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    padding: 0.4em;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial, helvetica;
}
```

Which results in something like this:

[image: Beer Me]

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs94m/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

A combination of twitter bootstrap with font awesome should be good to start with. 
Here are the links -
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/